# Create new json element and push element in json in Shopify liquid files

Tags: shopify, liquid

```
{% cartitems = [{ 
"id":1,"properties":{"_bundle_sku":"111""},"quantity":1},
{ "id":2,"properties":{"_bundle_sku":"222""},"quantity":1},
{ "id":3,"properties":{"_bundle_sku":"333""},"quantity":1},
{ "id":4,"properties":{"_bundle_sku":"222""},"quantity":1}
}] %}
```

This is for example I am getting result of my cart items and now I like to keep items together whose _bundle_sku values are same. But I don't find any help to manipulate cart json object in shopify liquid files.

So here I like the response to achieve like following -

```
{% cartitems = [{ 
"id":1,"properties":{"_bundle_sku":"111""},"quantity":1},
{ "id":2,"properties":{"_bundle_sku":"222""},"quantity":1},
{ "id":4,"properties":{"_bundle_sku":"222""},"quantity":1},
{ "id":3,"properties":{"_bundle_sku":"333""},"quantity":1}
}] %}
```

Please assist me how can I achieve this.
many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript. Liquid is not going to be of much help to you. Remember this basic pattern.

- Shopify renders Liquid server-side. Combines all the templates, snippets, assets into a huge string of HTML and dumps to your browser.
- Use Javascript once all the rendering is done to "do stuff". Your bundling use is a prime example. It becomes trivial to deal with "items" connected to other items using Javascript. Forget using Liquid for this purpose. It is not meant for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may use Ajax Cart API to do that with a /cart/update.js POST.
Documentation is available here:
https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart#post-cart-update-js

Comment: This is good I think. Every time I add to cart I will have to check item order and can update through this ajax call. I think this will make the work done. Anyway I fixed my issue in very manual way by using for loop and if conditions so first I listed out all the items which are not 222 SKU and then listed out all 222 SKU item products. This way I finished that temporarily. But I will try this very soon to fix this in a proper way. Many thanks Alice.